# My (Lua) Door script Doesn't work at all (I am VERY new)

Tags: lua, roblox

So I Coded a **D O O R** script to when *MouseClick* open door to coord, then click go to (OG) coord.
I have tried to re-write the code, I made some things capital and not capital, I checked the (.) and (:) and now I cant see any errors.

Here Is My Code

```
local Door = script.Parent
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local TweenStyle = TweenInfo.new(0.5, Enum.Easingstyle.Elastic.Out,0,false,0.)

local DoorOpen = {CFrame = CFrame.new(-54.66, 9.5, -9.056)}
local DoorClose = {CFrame = CFrame.new(-51.75, 9.5, -11)}

local OpenTween = TweenService:Create(Door,TweenStyle,DoorOpen)
local Closetween = TweenService:Create(Door,TweenStyle,DoorClose)

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    OpenTween:Play()
    wait(2)
    Closetween:Play()
end)
```

[SS of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De6zj.png)

Comment: "doesn't work at all" is not a useful description. explain the expected and observed behaviour of your code. are there any error messages? as is your post cannot be answered. do some own debugging. you could for example make sure your mouseclick is acutally handled by putting a print into the handler.

Comment: @Piglet What I expect to happen is when I click on the door then it would slide to X coords then when I click it again it would slide back. What I got is when I clik it I get a sound (door opening sound) but it doesnt move. And I've resolved all the errors but I cant find where I messed up, I'll try and llok for a vid on it now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax error in your code, you didn't write the right arguments in the "TweenInfo" at the third line. I fixed the code for you:

```
local Door = script.Parent
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local TweenStyle = TweenInfo.new(0.5, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.Out, 0, false, 0)

local DoorOpen = {CFrame = CFrame.new(-54.66, 9.5, -9.056)}
local DoorClose = {CFrame = CFrame.new(-51.75, 9.5, -11)}

local OpenTween = TweenService:Create(Door,TweenStyle,DoorOpen)
local Closetween = TweenService:Create(Door,TweenStyle,DoorClose)

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    OpenTween:Play()
    wait(2)
    Closetween:Play()
end)
```

For more information about "TweenInfo" check the API reference:
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/TweenInfo

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?